# Power BI. New measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate the number of values in a column with condition.
Table is

| Name | Index |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 0 |
| E | 1 |

I need to calculate the number of rows, where Index = 1. The result should be 3.

I tried different ways, conduct extensive googling, but no ones were working. I do not understand the reasons.
For example,

```
Measure = 
COUNTROWS(
    Filter(
        'Table', 
        'Table'[Index] = 1
    )
)
```

Could you, please, help me, explain what the problem is?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DAX expression should work. Alternatively, you can use this one:

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Table'),
    'Table'[Index] = 1
)
```

However, the problem must be somewhere else. The easiest way to check a measure is to put it into a **Card Visual**. The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, it is also not working. There is no mistake, while calculation (I mean a yellow bar doesn't apper). But when I put this figure into the blank table from Visualization, there is "Can't display this visual". I even do not know, whether it calculated something.

Comment: Please check your measure in a card visual like explained above.

Comment: I have checked. Thank you. It also does not represent anything. Yes, that is not the real example, but, to my mind, it is the similar. I completely do not comprehend, while it is not working on my data. Moreover, I put on the table (Visualization) the real parameter that is 1 or 0 as Index in this example, then choose Count (right click in Values), everything OK: It writes down 0 - 3000, 1 - 12000. It is strange that DAX expression is not working. I need this one value - 3000 for future graph (funnel).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have found the problem. In the column there were not numbers 0 and 1, but text 0 and 1. That's why I put ="1", everything now is working.